# (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<TimeOfDay?>' has no instance method 'format'. Receiver: Instance of 'Future<TimeOfDay?>'

Tags: flutter, dart

can somebody help me with my problem ? ,i want to make reminder by time i need to set the time but when i click the icon there's error like this "NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<TimeOfDay?>' has no instance method 'format'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<TimeOfDay?>'
Tried calling: format(Instance of 'StatefulElement'))"

the error come from here * i bold the error

```
_getTimefromUser({required bool isStartTime}) {
    var pickedTime = _showTimePicker();
    String _formatedTime = pickedTime.**format(context)**;
    if (pickedTime == null) {
      print('Time Canceled');
    } else if (isStartTime == true) {
      _startTime = _formatedTime;
    } else if (isStartTime == false) {
      _endTime = _formatedTime;
    }
  }

  _showTimePicker() {
    return showTimePicker(
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay(
        hour: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[0]),
        minute: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[1].split('')[0]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

please help me for my problem thank you

i was expecting that somebody can help me with that problem so i can continue my project

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
_getTimefromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async { /// update
    var pickedTime = await _showTimePicker(); /// update

    String _formatedTime = pickedTime.format(context);
    if (pickedTime == null) {
      print('Time Canceled');
    } else if (isStartTime == true) {
      _startTime = _formatedTime;
    } else if (isStartTime == false) {
      _endTime = _formatedTime;
    }
 }
```